# TemplateClasses depending on each other

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class NodeType, class EdgeType>
class GenericNetworkClass {
    typedef std::vector<EdgeType<NodeType>*> EdgesType;
    typedef std::vector<NodeType<EdgeType>*> NodesType;
    EdgesType EdgesList;
    NodesType NodesList;
}

template <class NodeType>
class GenericEdgeClass {
    std::vector<NodeType*> *Nodes;
    GenericNodeClass(std::vector<NodeType<GenericEdgeClass>*> *NodesPtr);
}

template <class EdgeType>
class GenericNodeClass {
    std::vector<EdgeType*> *Edges;
    GenericNodeClass(std::vector<EdgeType<GenericNodeClass>*> *EdgesPtr);
}
```

**In simple terms** I just want a `NetworkClass` with Template Nodes and Template Edges where

- the Nodes have access to the `EdgeList` from the Network via a pointer
- the Edges have acess to the `NodesList` from the Network via a pointer

All NodeTypes are derived from `GenericNodeClass` and all EdgeTypes are derived from `GenericEdgeClass`.

Obviously what I wrote does not work. What's the right approach here?
I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a language tag in future questions; this helps to attract the intended audience and enables automatic syntax highlighting.

Comment: Note that in `GenericEdgeClass`, you use `NodeType` both as a type and a template.

Comment: The constructor of `GenericEdgeClass` should not be `GenericNodeClass(...)`. I think it is a slip of the pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with cyclic dependencies with forward declarations, but your templates are strange: why should you enforce a class hierarchy, running into all types of covariance trouble, when you can make the user-defined classes for edges and nodes unconstrained "payloads"?

```
template <typename EdgeData, typename NodeData> class Edge;    
template <typename EdgeData, typename NodeData> class Node;

template <typename EdgeData, typename NodeData> class Edge{
    std::vector<Node<EdgeData, NodeData>*> *Nodes;
    EdgeData data;
    public:
    Edge(std::vector<Node<EdgeData, NodeData>*>  *NodesPtr, EdgeData & data);
    EdgeData getData();
    void addNode(Node<EdgeData, NodeData> & node);
    ...
}
template <typename EdgeData, typename NodeData> class Node{
    std::vector<Edge<EdgeData, NodeData>*> *Edges;
    NodeData data;
    public:
    Node(std::vector<Edge<EdgeData, NodeData>*>  *EdgesPtr, NodeData & data);
    NodeData getData();
    void addEdge(Edge<EdgeData, NodeData> & edge);
    ...
}
template <typename EdgeData, typename NodeData> class Hypergraph{
    private:
    std::vector<Edge<EdgeData, NodeData>*> edgesList;
    std::vector<Node<EdgeData, NodeData>*>  nodesList;
    ...
}
```

Better yet, exploit symmetry to reduce Edge and Node to a single class:

```
template <typename OwnData, typename DualData> class Entity{
    std::vector<Entity<DualData, OwnData>*> *duals;
    OwnData data;
    public:
    Entity(std::vector<Entity<DualData, OwnData>*>  *duals, OwnData & data);
    OwnData getData();
    void addDual(Entity<DualData, OwnData> & dual);
    ...
}
template <typename EdgeData, typename NodeData> class Hypergraph{
    private:
    std::vector<Entity<EdgeData, NodeData>*> edgesList;
    std::vector<Entity<NodeData, EdgeData>*>  nodesList;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! (I answered the follow up that myself)